# Width property on flex item not recognized in media query

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

So I have a 3-column layout, but for some reason in my middle column (the text column in the snippet) it keeps going all the way from edge to edge even though I have width for `.middle` set to 70%.

Divs and p's are block level elements but I'm not too sure why they remain 100% width after a specification in my media query, which you can find at the bottom of the code.

I want the p elements to have some room on the sides.

The class in question is the last listing in the media query.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  order: 1;
  //flex: 1 20%;
  width: 25%;
}
.left img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  order: 2;
  //flex: 2 20%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  order: 3;
  width: 25%;
  //flex: 1 50%;

}
div.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 300%;
  ;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
.right .list {
  // text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}
.list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.headbox h3 {
  color: orange;
}
#bigwrap {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  //position: absolute;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 70vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 5% auto 8% auto;
  background-color: white;
}
.container p {
  margin-bottom: 12%;
}
.container img {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.container img:first-child {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.middle p:first-child {
  margin-top: 8%;
}
.left,
.middle,
.right {
  // border-right: 1px solid blue;

}
.left img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  order: 2;
  flex: 2 20%;
}
.right .list {
  height: auto;
}
.list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.headbox h3 {
  color: orange;
}
.right .headbox {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@media all and(max-width: 800px) {
  #nav {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  #nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    /*updated*/
    margin-bottom: 7%;
  }
  #nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    /*added*/
  }
  #nav li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    /*updated*/
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  #nav li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 9%;
  }
  #bigwrap {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .container {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .left,
  .right {
    flex: 1 100%;
  }
  .middle {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bigwrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="cat1.jpeg" alt="Picture of kid" width="100px" height="100px">
      <img src="cat1.jpeg" alt="Picture of kid" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="box">
        <p>
          Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>
          Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>
          Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="headbox">
        <h3>Visit Us</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hours</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Plan</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Directions</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have `.middle` set to `width: 70%` in your media query.

But you also have `.middle` set to `flex: 2 20%` higher up in the code.

This rule is not in a media query, so it is always applied. It computes to:

- `flex-grow: 2`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 20%`

When your media query kicks-in, `width: 70%` overrides the `flex-basis: 20%`.

But `flex-grow: 2` and `flex-shrink: 1` remain intact, because you've got nothing stopping them.

So, the browser first applies `width: 70%`, and then `flex-grow: 2`, which consumes any remaining space on the line. (Hence, the content expands "edge to edge".)

*Make this adjustment in your media query:*

Instead of...

```
.middle { width: 70%`; }
```

use

```
.middle { flex: 0 0 70%; }
```

or

```
.middle { width: 70%; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; }
```

This will override all components of the other declaration.